Definition of local isometry in Do Carmo Differential Geometry
I'm having an issue trying to understand the definition of local isometry as given by do Carmo in his differential geometry book. He defines it as

A map $\phi: V → \bar S$ of a neighborhood $V$ of $p \in S$ is a
local isometry at $p$ if there exists a neighborhood $\bar V$ of $\phi(p) \in S$ such that
$\phi: V → \bar V$ is an isometry.

Taken at face value this seems to imply that a map $\phi$ is a local isometry if it is already an isometry with image set open on $\bar S$. This seems non-sensical and it won't help when doing the exercises. However in the author's Riemannian Geometry he defines it in an analogous way to the definition of local diffeomorphism. His new definition is thus (he mentions manifolds but the same thing applies to regular surfaces):

Let $M$ and $N$ be Riemannian manifolds. A differentiable mapping $f:M\to N$ is a local isometry at $p\in M$ if there is a neighborhood $U\in M$ of $p$ such that $f:U\to f(U)$ (I assume that he means the restriction to $U$) is a diffeomorphism satisfying (1).

By (1) he means (verbatim): "$\langle u,v\rangle =\langle df_p (u),df_p (v)\rangle _{f_(p)}$ for all $p\in M$, $u,v\in T_p M$" although in the context of the definition one must replace $M$ by $U$, I would guess.
These two definitions cannot even be equivalent since the first one considers only a function $V\subset S$ while the second one considers the function in question to have as a domain the whole surface (or manifold depending on what one is doing).
Similarly in the book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by Lee, he defines local isometry similarly (although he calls only function a local isometry iff for all $p$, $\phi$ is a local isometry at $p$ in the spirit of do Carmo's second definition):

$F$ is called a local isometry if every point $p \in M$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $F|_U$ is an isometry of $U$ onto an open subset of $\tilde M$.

Yet there is a crucial difference. He mentions that the range of the restriction of the function is open. Is it redundant or does it actually mean something?
Furthermore do Carmo defines the concept of a surface being locally isometric to another one as:

If there exists a local isometry into $\bar S$ at every $p \in S$,
the surface $S$ is said to be locally isometric to $\bar S$. $S$ and $\bar S$ are locally isometric if $S$ is locally isometric to $\bar S$ and $\bar S$ is locally isometric to $S$.

Lee however defines it as:

If each point of $M$ has a neighborhood that is isometric to an open subset of $(\tilde M,\tilde g)$, then we say that $(M,g)$ is locally isometric to $(\tilde M, \tilde g)$.

We can obtain an equivalent statementment by replacing "...isometric to an open subset (let's call it $U$)..." by there exists $h:U\to h(U)$ such that $h$
is an isometry. which is what two sets being isometric means.
This is a long post so let's summarize this in the following questions.

Concerning the definition of local isometry, which one is the correct one? I believe that the first one is poorly formulated. Even if so, which one should one take, do Carmo's second definition or Lee's?
Concerning the difference between do Carmo's second definition and Lee's. Why does one mention that the image set is open and the other doesn't? Is it redundant (I think it is) or crucial and why?
Concerning locally isometric surfaces, even if assuming that either do Carmo's second definition or Lee's definition of local isometry are good, the definitions of locally isometric surfaces do not seem to be equivalent. Do Carmo demands the existence of a local isometry at all $p$, but in his definition such functions are from $S\to\bar S$, and Lee's definition requires functions from a neighborhood of $S$ to another neighborhood of $\bar S$. Do Carmo's implies Lee's but not vice-versa I guess.
Most of the definitions in the whole post (except perhaps the first one) differ slightly from each other. Now authors are free to define things almosts anyway they wish, so it is a question of a mistake in either Lee or do Carmo or are they defining similar things? If such is the case is there a consensus among mathematicians?

If you could at least some some of these questions it would already be a great help!

All these definitions are different and all are common in the literature. Neither is "wrong." Is this state of affairs unsatisfactory? Yes, but eventually you will get used to it.

Indeed as I said in my question one can choose whatever definitions. But for example the first definition I write makes no sense, I would say, meaning it doesn't give us anything important. Furthermore between the second and third definitions why is it mentioned in the 3rd definition that the image must be open explicitly. Wouldn't that follow from the fact that we have a diffeomorphism? If the inverse is smooth we must have an open subset as the domain of the inverse, otherwise differentiation is not possible at the "edges" of the domain.

Why do you say that "it does not give us anything important?" It will not cure cancer or common cold, but it is a nontrivial restriction on a map. Diffeomorphism onto its image does not imply that the image is open in the target space. As for do Carmo's 2nd definition: he is sloppy and he meant to add that the image is open. (There are several other sloppily written places in his nice book.)

@MoisheKohan I find it odd that being a diffeomorphism between V->V' would not imply that V' is already open. The inverse function, being also smooth, requires its domain to be open. If e.g. V'=[a,b] we would have no diffeomorphism since the function would not be differentiable at "a" and "b". If you don't mind perhaps you could post a reply explaining things in more detail.

PS: regarding my last comment I can now see that the condition that the range must be open in the codomain is necessary if the dimensions of M and N are different. Otherwise one could have local diffeomorphisms from M\subset R^2 into part the xy plane, considering the codomain as R^3.

another thing that bothers me is that in other textbooks about differential geometry of riemannian geometry, no one uses the first definition ever, they only use the 2nd and/or 3rd definitions. Even do Carmo does it in his other book. I'm just worried that other theorems onwards in the book will depend on such definition and I might get things wrong when I get to other material outside this book.
